# Vector Projection by using operator and function

Tags: c++

I am doing Vector Projection on a Vector, but it fails, which can't build up.

I want to Calculate vector projection and output the Vector. But fail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;



int main () {
    3d p4(1, 2, 3);  // Constructor
    3d q4(4, 5, 6);
    3d ABCD(3d, 3d);
    3d r4 = ABCD(p4, q4);

  
    std::cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << setw(5) << r4.X << "," << setw(5) << r4.Y << "," << setw(5) << r4.Z << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Back when start I just got `3d Proj(3d &A)` and `3d operator/(float num)` functions to do the work done, it preset for me. Because the preset function can't input two vectors, I add `3d ABCD(3d V1, 3d V2)` to input two vectors and calculate two vectors.

what happen on my function`Projm`?

or is that have any way that can be done only by using `3d ABCD(3d &A)`?

Also, I cannot delete `3d Proj(3d &A)`, I need to use this.

Comment: Please note that, as coded, `b2` is mathematically (numerically it may not) equivalent to `b1`. Were you trying to write `float b1 = V2.X * V2.X + V2.Y * V2.Y + V2.Z * V2.Z; float b2 = sqrt(b1);`?

Comment: the assignment operator looks wrong, it normally would have the signature `Vector3D& operator=(const Vector3D&)`  and then `return *this;`

Comment: @Bob__ YES, that right

Answer (score 0):

There is such a function [hypot](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) in C++

```cpp
float b2 = hypot(V2.X, V2.Y, V2.Z);
```

instead of

```
int power = 2;
float b1 = (float)(pow(V2.X, power) + pow(V2.Y, power) + pow(V2.Z, power));
float b2 = pow(abs(sqrt(b1)), power);
```

This piece of code looks like nonsense:

```cpp
int main () {
...
    Vector3D Projm(Vector3D, Vector3D); ????
    Vector3D r4 = Projm(p4, q4); ????
```

It doesn't call the member function Projm by any mean. I wouldn't expect even to compile. It should look at least like this

```cpp
int main () {
...
    Vector3D x;
    Vector3D r4 = x.Projm(p4, q4);
```

What is the sense of Proj here?

```cpp
Vector3D Projm(Vector3D V1, Vector3D V2)
    {
        .....
        Vector3D Proj(V);
        return V;
    }
```

Get used to C++ operators, for instance divide and assign `/=`

```cpp
Vector3D operator/(float num)
    {
        // Return the scale vector
        Vector3D V(num);
        V.X /= num;
        V.Y /= num;
        V.Z /= num;
        return V;
    }
```

Also your Vector3D class works more like a package of function than a class. It is not OOP. It is no too different than set of global functions enclosed in a namespace.

Comment: The reason of the sense of Proj there is because I must use `Proj()` on the code, can,t delete or move out from the code, so I doing that action to fill up that rule.

Comment: @lemmonlola feel the difference between reason and reasoning. So, there is no reason, regardless of your reasoning. Fix your code.